# Array in Custom Query Spotfire

Tags: sql, spotfire

I have a drop-down list with fixed values as i then can adjust the display name. The drop-down list is connected as an input to a "load on demand" data table via a custom query.

I would like to have a list as an input. However, I cannot manage to make it work with multiple items.

In my query i have:

```
WHERE b.SomeFIELD IN (?parameter)
```

The parameter is linked to the documentproperty where the value is set as an array. It handles a single value perfectly. Multiple values do not work. I tried:

```
Value 1, value 2
"value 1", "value 2"
{"value 1", "value 2"}
```

Any ideas how to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: This is a common problem in databases, that parameter arguments always come across as _one_ value. In Sql Server I'd use a Table-Value Parameter or the `Split()` function, or avoid the `IN` condition entirely and insert each value as the user clicks it into a holding table I could use with a JOIN. Not sure about spotfire.

Comment: thanks joel, its exactly my problem. I'm going to look into the split function

Answer (score 1):

Spotfire passes that "array" as a comma separated string. You need to merely set the on demand setting to the property you created versus trying to edit the SQL in the information link. '

[Here's a good tutorial](https://community.tibco.com/wiki/limit-data-tibco-spotfirer-using-demand-multi-value-text-area-control-and-document-property)

Comment: HI scsimon, Thanks for your answer. I was aware of the tutorial. However, there a listbox is used. A listbox returns a "string list". A part from the fact that a dropdown list looks better, you can also add fixed values, but i get the feeling its only one fixed value as "string" not an array...

It think it passes "value 1, value2, value 3" through instead of a list. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, i would think it is passes as a comma separated string, not a list/array. I suppose i should have used a better word than list in my original answer

Comment: Hi It passes a comma separated string but it cannot handle Functions so I cannot split the string to a list. Any idea?

Comment: what can't handle functions, your data source? What kind of SQL database is the data stored in?